# Using data from delegate after NSURLConnection has finished

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I've made an NSURLConnection, and made a seperate class to be used as a delegate, but I can't make use of the delegates data after the connection has finished. The data writes to console from within the delegate class, but not outside.

In the ServerCommunicationDelegate-class (the delegate), in method "connectionDidFinishLoading":

```
self.errorLog  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(self.errorLog); // Prints the data to console
```

In the class where the connection takes place:

```
ServerCommunicationDelegate *del = [[ServerCommunicationDelegate alloc] init];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:del];
NSLog(@"Errorlog %@", del.errorLog); // Returns null
```

"errorLog" is a property of "ServerCommunicationDelegate".

Is there something I misunderstood about the delegation-paradigm here, or is it maybe something else I've missed?

Either way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` works asynchronously. The line

```
NSLog(@"Errorlog %@", del.errorLog); // Returns null
```

is executed before the connection has finished loading (probably before it even started
loading).

Comment: Aha, knew I had missed something. Thanks!